# Number of different pizza toppings

Tags: combinatorics

Krishna is preparing a pizza with 8 slices, and he has 10 toppings to put on the pizza. He can put only one
topping on each slice but can use the same topping on zero or more slices. In how many different ways can
he prepare the slices so that the same topping is not used in adjacent slices?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you thought about asking yourself how many choices he has for the first slice, how many he then has for the adjacent slice etc.?

Comment: If you have just 2 toppings, is the answer 1 or 2? In other words, are two pizzas considered different if they differ only by a rotation?

Comment: @Mattos My guess is that the OP has already thought about that and found out it's not so simple, that's why he's asking the question. Of course he should have made it clear what he's tried.

Comment: I thought about some possible solutions. So if there is not restriction on the placement then there are $10^8$ possibilities. If we apply restriction mentioned in the problem, he has 10 possibilities for the first slice and 9 possibilities for the second slice and 9 possibilities for the third slice and so on. So the answer would be $10.9^6 .8$ possibilities because the last slice shouldn't have the topping from first slice and 7th slice. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering the case where two pizzas are considered different if they differ by rotation. As the OP suggested in the comments, there are 10 choices for the first slice and 9 for the second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh slice. However, it is incorrect to assume that there are eight choices left for the eighth slice: if the seventh slice has the same topping as the first, then there are nine choices. To consider the amount of possible toppings for the lasts slice, we must thus calculate the probability that the toppings of the first and seventh slice are the same. Let us denote $P[T_k]$ the probability of the $k^{th}$ slice having the same topping $T$ as the first slice. For a valid pizza, we get:

$$P[T_k] = \frac{0}{9} P[T_{k-1}] + \frac{1}{9} P[\neg T_{k-1}] = \frac{1}{9} (1-P[T_k])$$

Since $P[T_2] = 0$, we get:

$$P[T_7] = \frac{1}{9}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{9}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{9}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{9}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{9}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)\bigg) = \frac{12536380}{125361677} = 0.1000016935$$

The total number of possible pizzas, not considering rotation, is then:

$$10 \cdot 9^6 \cdot(P[T_7] \cdot 9 + P[\neg T_7] \cdot 8) = 43,046,730$$

Update: the following Python program evaluates the number of valid pizzas for $n$ slices and $k$ toppings. For $n=8$ and $k=10$, the output indeed equals $43,046,730$.

```
import itertools

n = 8
k = 10
i = 0
for t in itertools.product(range(k), repeat=n):
  v = 1
  for s in range(n):
    if t[s] == t[(s+1)%n]:
      v = 0
      break
  i += v
print(i)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate $$P[T_k] = \frac{0}{9} P[T_{k-1}] + \frac{1}{9} P[\neg T_{k-1}] = \frac{1}{9} (1-P[T_k])$$. How did you arrive at this equation?

Comment: @papabiceps If the topping on the previous slice is the same as the one on the first slice, the current slice cannot have this topping and thus, the probability of having the same topping is $\frac{0}{9}$. If the topping on the previous slice is however different from the one on the first slice, the probability of having the same topping as the first slice equals $\frac{1}{9}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is some recursion formula that can be achieved to solve the problem for arbitrary many slides of pizza (with a fixed order). For pizzas that are considered equal if they just differ by rotation we can extend that result using burnside's lemma.

For the fixed ordering:
Let $n$ denote the number of slides of pizza and $a_n$ denote the number of valid pizzas. For $n=1$, we have 10 different solutions, for $n=2$ we have $90=10\cdot 9$ different solutions and for $n=3$, we have $10\cdot 9\cdot 8$ different solutions.
For $n\geq 4$ we seperate the cases whether the slides number 1 and $n-1$ have the some topping or not.
If they do have the same topping, removing the slides $n-1$ and $n$ gives us a "smaller pizza" with the wanted structure and for slide $n$, there are 9 possible toppings (as both slides text to that have the same topping).

If 1 and $n-1$ have different toppings removing only slide $n$ gives us a smaller pizza of the same type and for slide $n$, there are just $8$ possible toppings. Thus for $n\geq 4$ we get $$a_n=8a_{n-1}+9a_{n-2}.$$

Solving this equation (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) we get $a_n=9^n+8\cdot(-1)^n$. For $n=8$, we thus get 43 046 730 possibilities.

A more abstract way for what we have done so far is saying that there are $n$ different objects in a circle that are colored in 10 possible ways so that no neighbours have the same color (=topping).

If pizzas are identified when they differ by rotation let us call the slices $1, \ldots 8$ and we let operate the group $G$ generated by the permutation $\sigma:=(1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8)$ on the set $S$ containing those 43 046 729 different pizzas from above in the obvious manner. We have to count the number of orbits of this set under the given operation. Thus we have to compute the number of fixed toppings under each of the 8 group elements. Note that $\sigma^k$ for $k\in \{1,\ldots, 8\}$ is a permutation consisting of $k$ cycles of length $\frac{8}{\mathrm{ggT}(8, k)}$. A pizza is fixed under a permutation if all the slices in one cycle have the same topping.

For $\sigma^0$ we thus have 43 046 729 fixed pizzas.
For $\sigma^k$ with $k\in\{1,3,5,7\}$ we have 0 fixed pizzas.
For $\sigma^k$ with $k\in\{2,6\}$ we have 90 fixed pizzas.
For $\sigma^4$ we have 6570 fixed pizzas (these can be counted similar to first case). Thus, according to burnsides lemma, we have 
$$ \frac18\cdot (43046730+4\cdot0+2\cdot90+ 6570)= 5381685$$
such pizzas.

Comment: Thank you for the extended version :)